# Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, metadata

I am new to using pandas and I'm attempting to fix the last portion of my script. When calling the following function I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column place_name
```

```
def get_place_name(latitude, longitude):
    location = geolocator.reverse(f"{latitude}, {longitude}", exactly_one=True)
    if location is None:
        return None
    else:
        return location.address
```

This function is being called from here:

```
metadata_df = extract_metadata(dir_path)
print("[+] Metadata extracted from all image files")
print(metadata_df.columns)
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="exif_location")
metadata_df['place_name'] = metadata_df.apply(
    lambda row: get_place_name(
        row['gps_latitude'], row['gps_longitude']),
    axis=1)
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Please make a [mre] including enough code to reproduce the error (and only that much) and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Answer (score 1):

Your code works well for me (Pandas 1.5.3, Geopy 2.3.0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat': [34.053691, 40.712728],
                   'lon': [-118.242766, -74.006015]})

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='MyApp')

df['place_name'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_place_name(x['lat'], x['lon']), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output

```
         lat         lon                                         place_name
0  34.053691 -118.242766  Los Angeles City Hall, 200, North Spring Stree...
1  40.712728  -74.006015  New York City Hall, 260, Broadway, Lower Manha...
```

I don't understand why your function try to return a dataframe with multiple columns. Your error is reproducible if you do something like:

```
df['place_name'] = df[['lat', 'lon']]
...
ValueError: Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column place_name
```

Answer (score 0):

## Empty Input DataFrame

Here is a minimal, reproducible example.

### No error if Data Frame has one or more rows

```
from geopy import Nominatim
import pandas as pd
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="exa-app")

def get_place_name(latitude, longitude):
    location = geolocator.reverse(f"{latitude}, {longitude}", exactly_one=True)
    if location is None:
        return None
    else:
        return location.address

ndf = pd.read_csv('nyc.csv', sep=r'\t', engine='python')
ndf
```

|  | Name | Lat | Long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Times Square | 40.758896 | -73.985130 |
| 1 | Statue of Liberty | 40.689167 | -74.044444 |

```
ndf['place_name'] = ndf.apply(
    lambda row: get_place_name(
        row['Lat'], row['Long']),
    axis=1)
ndf
```

|  | Name | Lat | Long | place_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Times Square | 40.758896 | -73.985130 | Duffy Square, Manhattan Community Board 5, Man... |
| 1 | Statue of Liberty | 40.689167 | -74.044444 | Statue of Liberty, Flagpole Plaza, Manhattan C... |

### An an error is possible if the input data frame has no rows

```
zdf = pd.read_csv('nul.csv', sep=r'\t', engine='python')
zdf
```

|  | Name | Lat | Long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

```
zdf['place_name'] = zdf.apply(
    lambda row: get_place_name(
        row['Lat'], row['Long']),
    axis=1)

ValueError: Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column place_name
```

### Reason

apply() evaluates to an empty DataFrame with multiple columns.

```
za = zdf.apply(
    lambda row: get_place_name(
        row['Lat'], row['Long']),
    axis=1)
za.describe()
```

|  | Name | Lat | Long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| count | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| unique | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| top | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| freq | NaN | NaN | NaN |